# How can I find/plot $f(t)$ if I only have $f(t+\Delta t)$ and $f(0)$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

So, I am working on a game, and I need to come up with some math formulas for a proof of concept (and tweak them to make sure it's balanced). In particular, I have a quantity $y$ that should decrease over time with a specific pattern. As is often the case in games, this quantity will be stored in a variable, and the new value of this variable will be re-computed every frame starting from the current value and the time passed since last frame $\Delta t$.

Through trial and error, I came up with this formula to compute the new value of $y$:
$$
y_{new}=\frac{y_{old}}{((k)^{y_{old}})^{\Delta t}}
$$
where $k$ is a constant parameter such that $k>1$,  $y$ will always be $>1$ (meaning that if it goes below 1 I will discard the value and consider $y=1$ instead), and $\Delta t$ is a value in seconds always $>0$.
Now, this "formula" is okay from a coding perspective, it's ready to be implemented, but I would like to be able to plot it on Geogebra or Wolfram Alpha in order to analyze and tweak it as needed, and for that I need to transform it in a "traditional" function $y=f(t, y_0)$.
How do I do that?

I don't even know what to Google (I guess it's something in the realm of differential equations?), so it would be nice if you could explain the reasoning/point me to a general explanation so I can further research the topic, as I expect that I will face similar problems multiple times over the course of the development.

Comment: So your function is defined as:$$f(x+\Delta x)=\frac{f(x)}{k^{f(x)\Delta x}}$$?

Comment: @MathAndPhysics To be clear, the exponent of $k$ is $f(x)^{\Delta x}$, not $f(x)\Delta x$ (I can't tell which one you wrote in the comment, sorry)

Comment: @RiccardoVailati Beware that in exponentiation, the order matters. In particular, $a^{(b^c)}$ does not equal $(a^b)^c$ in general (i.e., exponentiation is not *associative*). In your question body, you have $(a^b)^c$ (which is equivalent to what the user MathAndPhysics wrote) but in your comment, you are suggesting that it's $a^{(b^c)}$ (i.e., the upper exponentiation is performed first).

Comment: @Jam right, I somehow forgot basic math, sorry. MathAndPhysics was right, it is $(k^{f(x)})^{\Delta x}$, disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking to solve for your function is, as you correctly noted, a [*differential equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation). (Or rather, a [*difference equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#difference_equation) since you are taking discrete steps of time, rather than continuous ones, but the two are intimately related, in any case.)

Your proposed differential equation gives a nice, simple solution provided the time steps are small. If we take logarithms of both sides, we can convert the multiplicative operations into additive ones

$$y(t_0+\Delta t)=\frac{y(t_0)}{k^{y(t_{0}){\Delta t}}}
\\\ln y(t_0+\Delta t)=\ln{y(t_0)}-{y(t_{0}){\Delta t}}\ln\left({k}\right)$$

Denoting $\ln y(\cdot)$ by $L(\cdot)$ and rearranging, we have

$$\frac{L(t_0+\Delta t)-L(t_0)}{\Delta t}=-\ln k \, e^{L(t_0)}$$

where the LHS is a difference quotient. Provided $\Delta t\approx 0$, we can consider this to be approximately the derivative of $L$. I'll leave it to you to solve $L'(t)=-\ln k \, e^{L(t)}$ and back-substitute for $y$.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was not sure it was actually a differential equation because it didn't include $f'(x)$ directly, I assumed there was a way to transform it but I couldn't figure out how. Most of the material I was able to find online about differential equations seems to assume that the starting point is something like your last equation, and I didn't know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: You end up with something like $y(t) =\dfrac{1}{t \log_e(k) +C}$ where you can adjust the $C$ to fit your initial conditions